# MVC application running on EC2 instance can't acess RDS database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm developing an application with MVC that uses a remote database (`RDS amazon`) to populate the data of the application. Running the application locally everything works fine. The problem occurrs when I deploy the application to an `EC2 instance`, my online application can't acess the same `RDS database`. What is the correct procedure to enable the `EC2 instance` to acess the `RDS database` ? My security group has at inbound and outbound permissions for all trafic and anywhere enabled.

Comment: Do you mean the security group for the EC2 instance or the security group for the RDS instance?

Comment: Both share the same security group @jbird

Comment: When I run the application using the RDS endpoint as my connection string in my machine everything works @jbird

Comment: If you can connect to the RDS instance from your local machine the issue is on the EC2 intance. Check the Windows Server Firewall, try disabling it completely, and check the security groups. Also, if they are on the same VPC try connecting via the private ip

Comment: Can you connect to the RDS database from your EC2 instance using `sqlcmd`?

Comment: @BrianArmstrong I don't have `sqlcmd` in my enviorment, Should I have it? Can I use Telnet for this test purpouse?

Comment: You could try `telnet myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com 1433`. Depending on the error message you get, it could help narrow down the cause.

Comment: @BrianArmstrong Using `telnet`, after a time, a received the following response: `Press any key to continue...` this is positive?

Comment: There should be some output from the telnet command itself.

Comment: Hi @JulianoOliveira, did you solve this issue? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **How do I resolve problems connecting to my Amazon RDS database instance?**

### Issue

> I am unable to connect to my Amazon RDS database instance.

### Your Problem:

> When attempting to connect from an EC2 instance that is not in a VPC,
>   the DB instance's security group is not configured to allow access by
>   the EC2 instance.

### Solution:

If attempts to connect from an EC2 classic instance fail, grant user access from the DB instance security group. For more information, check through the following:

If you want to access your DB instance from an Amazon EC2 instance, you must first determine if your EC2 instance and DB instance are in a VPC. If you are using a default VPC, you can assign the same EC2 or VPC security group that you used for your EC2 instance when you create or modify the DB instance that the EC2 instance will access.

If your DB instance and EC2 instance are not in a VPC, you must configure the DB instance's security group with an ingress rule that allows traffic from the Amazon EC2 instance. You would do this by adding the Amazon EC2 security group for the EC2 instance to the DB security group for the DB instance. In this example, you add an ingress rule to a DB security group for an Amazon EC2 security group.

### Important

> Adding an ingress rule to a DB security group for an Amazon EC2
>   security group only grants access to your DB instances from Amazon EC2
>   instances associated with that Amazon EC2 security group.
>
> You can't authorize an Amazon EC2 security group that is in a
>   different AWS region than your DB instance. You can authorize an IP
>   range, or specify an Amazon EC2 security group in the same region that
>   refers to IP address in another region. If you specify an IP range, we
>   recommend that you use the private IP address of your Amazon EC2
>   instance, which provides a more direct network route from your Amazon
>   EC2 instance to your Amazon RDS DB instance, and does not incur
>   network charges for data sent outside of the Amazon network.

### AWS Management Console

To add an EC2 security group to a DB security group

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon RDS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.
2. Select Security Groups from the navigation pane on the left side of the console window.
3. Select the details icon for the DB security group you want to grant access.

[image]

4. In the details page for your security group, select, select EC2 Security Group from the Connection Type drop-down list, and then select the Amazon EC2 security group you want to use. Then click Authorize.

[image]

5. The status of the ingress rule will be authorizing until the new ingress rule has been applied to all DB instances that are associated with the DB security group that you modified. After the ingress rule has been successfully applied, the status will change to authorized.

### CLI

To grant access to an Amazon EC2 security group, use the AWS CLI command authorize-db-security-group-ingress.

**Example**

### For Linux, OS X, or Unix:

```
aws rds authorize-db-security-group-ingress \
    --db-security-group-name default  \
    --ec2-security-group-name myec2group \
    --ec2-security-group-owner-id 987654321021
```

### For Windows:

```
aws rds authorize-db-security-group-ingress ^
    --db-security-group-name default  ^
    --ec2-security-group-name myec2group ^
    --ec2-security-group-owner-id 987654321021
```

The command should produce output similar to the following:

```
SECGROUP  Name     Description 
SECGROUP  default  default
      EC2-SECGROUP  myec2group  987654321021  authorizing
```

### API

To authorize network access to an Amazon EC2 security group, call that Amazon RDS API function, http://docs.aws.amazon.com//AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress.htmlAuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress with the following parameters:

```
EC2Security­GroupName = myec2group

EC2SecurityGroupOwnerId = 987654321021
```

Example

```
https://rds.amazonaws.com/
    ?Action=AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress
    &EC2SecurityGroupOwnerId=987654321021
    &EC2Security­GroupName=myec2group
    &Version=2009-10-16
    &SignatureVersion=2
    &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
    &Timestamp=2009-10-22T17%3A10%3A50.274Z
    &AWSAccessKeyId=<AWS Access Key ID>
    &Signature=<Signature>
```

### Resource Link:

1. [How do I resolve problems connecting to my Amazon RDS database
   instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/)
2. [Authorizing Network Access to a DB Instance from an Amazon EC2
   Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.AuthorizingEC2)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following are done.

1. Create a VPC security group (for example, "sg-appsrv1") and define
   inbound rules that use as source the IP addresses of the client
   application. This security group allows your client application to
   connect to EC2 instances in a VPC that uses this security group.
2. Create an EC2 instance for the application and add the EC2 instance
   to the VPC security group ("sg-appsrv1") you created in the previous
   step. The EC2 instance in the VPC shares the VPC security group with
   the DB instance.
3. Create a second VPC security group (for example, "sg-dbsrv1") and
   create a new rule by specifying the VPC security group you created
   in step 1 ("sg-appsrv1") as the source.
4. Create a new DB instance and add the DB instance to the VPC security
   group ("sg-dbsrv1") you created in the previous step. When you
   create the instance, use the same port number as the one specified
   for the VPC security group ("sg-dbsrv1") rule you created in step 3.

Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.Scenarios

Answer (score 0):

By default RDS does not allow any connection that is not specified within the Security Group (SG). You can allow based on CIDR addressing or by Amazon account number which would allow any EC2 under that account to access it.

but also check:

- Do the associated Subnets seem properly configured?
- Are the Subnets part of a Routing Group that seems properly configured (Internet Gateway specified, etc?)
- Does the RDS say it's Publicly Accessible?
- And of course check the RDS Security Group and EC2 Security Group

  - Don't forget your actual source IP may be an internal IP (if accessing internally via a VPC) or an external IP (which may be a router's IP, or an EC2 instance's Instance IP which is distinct from its Load Balancer / Elastic IP) -- to troubleshoot, you may try to allow access to all IPs and ports.

(The routing group was my problem; in creating a new subnet, I neglected to add it to a routing group with a gateway.)